# Getting disordered sort result via elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm a beginner with `elasticsearch`, I have a list of articles, with a `articleReferenceName` property, and I'm trying to **sort** them alphabetically via `articleReferenceName`, but they are not sorted correctly, maybe because the articles are not indexed correctly...Can some one help me to fix the filter configuration, and figure out the problem please. I think I issed some frnesh filter
This is the yaml configuration of the analyzers and filters defintions:

```
 elasticsearch:
        synonyms_file: "%es_synonyms_file%"

        # https://gist.github.com/dadoonet/2146038
        # http://obtao.com/blog/2013/10/configure-elasticsearch-on-an-efficient-way/
        settings:
            number_of_shards:   5
            number_of_replicas: 1
            index:
                mapping.total_fields.limit: 10000
                max_result_window: 500000
                analysis:
                    analyzer:
                        francais_synonym:
                            type: custom
                            tokenizer: standard
                            filter: [ lowercase, custom_synonyms, asciifolding, fr_stopwords, fr_snowball, elision, worddelimiter ]
                        francais_search:
                            type: custom
                            tokenizer: standard
                            filter: [ lowercase, asciifolding, fr_stopwords, fr_snowball, elision, worddelimiter ]
                        starts_with:
                            tokenizer: keyword
                            filter: lowercase
                        starts_with_numeric:
                            tokenizer: keyword
                            filter: [ lowercase, worddelimiter_numeric ]
                        full_text:
                            tokenizer: keyword
                            filter: [ lowercase, asciifolding ]
                        regions:
                            tokenizer: keyword
                            filter: [ lowercase, worddelimiter_regions ]
                    filter:
                        fr_stopwords:
                            type: stop
                            stopwords: [_french_]
                        fr_snowball:
                            type: snowball
                            language: French
                        fr_stemmer:
                            type: stemmer
                            name: french
                        elision:
                            type: elision
                            articles: [ l, m, t, qu, n, s, j, d ]
                        worddelimiter:
                            type: word_delimiter
                        worddelimiter_regions:
                            type: word_delimiter
                            generate_word_parts:     false
                            split_on_case_change:    false
                            split_on_numerics:       false
                            stem_english_possessive: false
                        custom_synonyms:
                            type: synonym
                            synonyms_path: "%es_synonyms_file%"
                        worddelimiter_numeric:
                            type:                    word_delimiter
                            generate_word_parts:     false
                            generate_number_parts:   false
                            catenate_numbers:        true
                            split_on_case_change:    false
                            split_on_numerics:       false
                            stem_english_possessive: false
                            preserve_original:       true

         article:
                mappings:
                    article:
                        _source:
                            enabled: true
                        properties:
                            id:
                                type: integer
                            articleReferenceName:
                                type: text
                                analyzer:  francais_synonym
                                search_analyzer: francais_search
                            aggs:
                                type: object
                                properties:
                                    articleReferenceName:
                                        type: text
                                        index: not_analyzed
                                        fielddata: true
```

PS: I gonna accept any edit improvement on this question.

Comment: `articleReferenceName` is of type text and hence this is why the sorting doesn't work. You need to create a keyword sub-field for that field and use that one for sorting.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I'm gonna use that for sorting and aggregation, so the alst config gonne be like this `   articleReferenceName:
                                        type: keyword
                                        index: not_analyzed ` not need to add a normalizer ?

Comment: Only `articleReferenceName: type: keyword`, no need for `index: not_analyzed` nor any normalizer.

Comment: can can you explain to me the reason of using index: not_analyzed, and the reason and why we need to use a normalizer, because the doc seems not clear at all. Thank you

Comment: `type: text + index: not_analyzed` is only for ES 2.x, as of ES 5.x you need to use `type: keyword` instead. A normalizer is only a kind of analyzer for keyword fields.

Comment: then I think we need to mention a normalizer I think.... why we need to mlention analyzer to other and not with type: keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I got a solution for my problem to sort or perform some aggregation feature, base on the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) we need to make the type as `keyword` to make the mapping index looks like this:

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "_doc": {
            "properties": {
                "articleReferenceName": { "type": "keyword" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, the main reason of using `index: not_analyzed` option is to add the field value to the index unchanged, as a **single term**.
 This is the default for all fields that support this option except for string fields. `not_analyzed` fields are usually used with term-level queries for structured search.